# Object Array format output

Tags: powershell, object, format, output

```
$HTML = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URI

$pricebf = ($HTML.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("div") | Where{ $_.className -eq 'price_display' } ).innerText | select-object -First 1
```

This code returns $4.95 $4.50 (there is a space in between these two values. I only require to output the last value. $4.50 , Thank you

Answer (score 0):

We are not suppose to do your homework, However...

You can use `-split` to cut the string in the space between, then use the last result in the array, like this:

`($pricebf -split '\s')[1]`

Of course in case the result will looks different each time, you may better use Regex

Answer (score 0):

homework haha right, tried the code above didn't work? , did some more study and sorted it out. New to PowerShell but looks like there are so many possibilities to sort the correct answer , thanks for your time still appreciate your efforts.

```
$price = $pricebf.Substring($pricebf.LastIndexOf("$"), $pricebf.Length - $pricebf.LastIndexOf("$"))
```